# Front End Query and PHP SQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to submit a query from a site to retrieve certain records from a MySQL db. When I execute the query from the site form, I get the  mysql_error() return of 'Invalid query: Query was empty' when I know it's not empty.

```
$Level = $_POST['level'];
$Year  = $_POST['year'];
$Name  = $_POST['name'];
$Award  = $_POST['award'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT *
    FROM wineawards
    WHERE LEVEL = $Level
      OR YEAR = $Year
      OR name = $Name
      OR award = $Award

    ");

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Not sure if I am missing something here, or typing something wrong?

Comment: always check you POST values and wrap your variables with single quotes like this `'$Level'` ,`'$Year'`..and others

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: check your POST variables, like, $Level = isset($_POST['level']) ? $_POST['level'] : '';            and in the query use single quotes $query = mysql_query("SELECT *
    FROM wineawards
    WHERE `LEVEL` = '$Level'
      OR `YEAR` = '$Year'
      OR `name` = '$Name'
      OR `award` = '$Award'

    ");

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *
    FROM wineawards
    WHERE LEVEL = '$Level'
      OR YEAR = '$Year'
      OR name = '$Name'
      OR award = '$Award'

    ");

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: why this does not provide an answer

Comment: I believe I misread the question, I'm updating my recommendation

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *
  FROM wineawards
  WHERE LEVEL = '" . $Level . "'
  OR YEAR = '" . $Level . "'
  OR name = '" . $Name . "'
  OR award = '" . $Award . "'

 ");
```